# Send session value in database

Tags: php, mysql

**$_SESSION['logged']** is associated with an email adress for every logged user.

When the user complete a form and send it to database, I want to send that session (email adress) too.

I tried two options:

1) passing the session in a variable `$owner = $_SESSION['logged']`

2) inserting it directly with `$sql="INSERT INTO contacts(name, email, owner) VALUES('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]', '$_SESSION[logged]')";`

None of them worked. Also, I didn't get any error, just a blank page after submit.
I'm missing something?

Comment: You probably have errors turned off. You will want to show all errors so you can properly see what's going on.

Comment: @Andrew, if I write "logged" I get a syntax error because of first opened " (before INSERT INTO).

Comment: Sorry,  '$_SESSION[logged]' could be  $_SESSION['logged'] instead. Need the quotes around logged somehow, otherwise won't work.

Comment: @Andrew Although it is the correct way without raising notices, that isn't the issue `$array[field]` will work just as well as `$array['field']`.

Comment: @user140102 Do a `var_dump($_SESSION);` what do you get.

Comment: @AzizSaleh, I get array(1) { ["logged"]=> string(24) "email.adress@gmail.com" }

Comment: Finally, I did it with `$_POST['logged'] = $_SESSION['logged'];`. Thank you for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways of going about this. You can either create a hidden input field like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="logged" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['logged']; ?>" />
```

or you can simply set a `$_POST['logged'] = $_SESSION['logged'];`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the statement to insert the data into the database, does it look like:

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

If so, change it to:

```
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will display the error if it is a mysql error.